# If xy + yz + zx = 1, ...........

Tags: trigonometry

If $xy + yz + zx = 1$, then show that

> $$\dfrac{x}{1-x^2} + \dfrac{y}{1-y^2} + \dfrac{z}{1-z^2} = \dfrac{4xyz}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}$$

I tried doing the sum algebraically, that is, by solving the LHS but, that method isn't really getting us anywhere.

Also, I found this sum in an a book on trigonometry. So how can I solve it with trigonometry?

Comment: Hint: If $A+B+C = \pi/2$, then $\tan A \tan B + \tan B \tan C + \tan A \tan C = 1$

Comment: @ParthKohli I THOUGHT that's how you do it,it's a consequence of the product-sum tangent formulas!

Comment: @ParthKohli, I followed your suggestion :-  <br/> I found LHS = tanA/(1-$\tan^2$ A) + tanB/(1- $\tan^2$B) +tanC/(1-$\tan^2$C) <br/> = (tan2Atan2Btan2C)/2..... but what next?

Answer (score 3):

For a trigonometric proof, follow Parth Kohli's suggestion which is nice. Meanwhile here's an algebraic proof.

Let $a=\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$, $b=\dfrac{y}{1-y^2}$, $c=\dfrac{z}{1-z^2}$.

We need to prove: $a+b+c=4abc$, i.e. $\sum \dfrac{1}{ab}=4$.

We have $\sum \dfrac{1}{ab}=\sum \dfrac{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}{xy}=1 + \sum \left( \dfrac{1}{xy}-(\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}) \right)$.

Now, $\sum \dfrac{1}{xy}=\sum \dfrac{xy+yz+zx}{xy}=3+\sum (\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x})$, 
which gives the desired equality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\tan \frac{1}{2}A$, etc for $y,z$ and $B,C$. Using the sum of three angles formula,  the condition $xy+yz+xz=1$ implies that
$$\cos \frac{1}{2}(A+B+C)=0.$$

Now $$\tan A=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$ so the result to be shown is
$$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C$$ and this is equivalent, assuming that none of the $\cos A$ etc  are non zero, to $$\sin(A+B+C)=0.$$ The result now follows from the zeros of $\cos$ and $\sin$.